# ggplot2 Unequal geom_bar stack size

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm having a problem using geom_bar to draw comparisons between two sample classification methods where I want to show that the same samples by classifier A can result in different outcomes than by classifier B.

An example of how I've been attempting this is as follows -

```
library("ggplot2")
dfr <- data.frame(class=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE), 
                  classifier=rep(c("A", "B"), c(5, 5)), 
                  id=rep(paste("X_", 1:5, sep = ""), 2))
```

Here we have the data.frame giving us information on Classifier, Class and Sample Ids

We can display this to show how the proportion of each class is altered depending on which classifier is used

```
ggplot(dfr, aes(x = classifier, fill = class)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="bin")
```

However, if I want to compare samples to themselves (i.e. to have the same samples next to each other to see exactly which samples have changed and to what) I use the following code

```
ggplot(dfr, aes(x=classifier, y=as.factor(id), fill=class)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="WHITE")
```

This is where my problem is. As you can see for some reason the area of the stacked sections are much larger the further up the bar you look and I'm at a loss as to how to force the size to be the same.

Any recommendations as to how best to remedy this so the section areas are equal and the Id labels adjacent to their designated section would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! `geom_bar` is trying to perform aggregation, which is only valid for numeric data. For your case, will `+ geom_tile(colour = "white")` work instead?

Comment: So simple! Thanks for the quick reply and it works perfectly on my actual data.

Dominic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping my comment into an answer:

```
ggplot(dfr, aes(x = classifier, y = id, fill = class)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "white")
```

[image]